# /dev/shm (shared memory) on linux

Tags: linux, unix, memory-usage

Let's imagine that we have 8Gb of RAM on server. 
I'm mounting /dev/shm with 4Gb on board.

```
mount -o remount,size=4G /dev/shm
```

Will this memory be **strictly reserved** for shared memory or if /dev/shm is empty this memory could be used by regular applications (web server, php etc.)?

PS:Sorry for my English.

I'm asking it because I've just checked `df -h` and found `tmpfs                 6.0G     0  6.0G   0% /dev/shm` on 8Gb RAM sever. I don't know who made this setup, but it seems to me awful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not 'reserved'.  It only uses as much RAM as needed.  By default (if you don't specify size) it will be 50% the total RAM size.

You only need to worry if you're consistently filling it.

Comment: @Javier, hello! Thank you for your answer. Please, could you tell me when I can read about it?

Comment: See http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.33/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt